# How to setup guest session to be able to run MythTV Frontend and LIRC

Tags: 16.04, permissions, guest-session, mythbuntu, lirc

I made a guest-prefs account to setup guest session like advised in 
[related Ubuntu document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession). However, LIRC and MythTV Frontend do not work in guest session then, but work in guest-prefs account.
When `mythtfrontend.real` is trying to enable LIRC, it fails to connect to  Unix socket '/dev/lircd'. mythfrontend does not seem to use ~/.mythtv/config.xml even if it uses ~/.mythtv as configuration directory according to output in terminal. Thus it is unable to connect to database. It does not find Mythbuntu theme even if it is stored in ~/.mythtv/themes/Mythbuntu

[mythtfrontend.real output in guest session](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23758583/)

Comment: That may require some editing of `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm`